# Google Sheets: Trying to get values for Data in a column and row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

Not sure I was able to explain myself too well in the title so here it goes:

I have been trying to figure this one out using the Filter function, but I am unable to make it work, and I am sure there must be an easy way to do it. The idea is that I have a column with the names of the members of a team, and each team member needs to perform a number of actions in a set of tasks. I am counting the amount of actions performed by each team member on each task, and trying to filter those by team member and by task.

So it goes like this: I have a list of names in column B. The number of actions in column C and the task would be selected from a dropdown menu done with 'Data validation'. When I select the task from my drop down menu, the number of actions would change to reflect the actions performed per agent on the selected task.

I added an example too. In the example I filtered the data in sheet 'Data' by names, but I don't know how to add a criteria that would also filter by the tasks on row 1 in the sheet 'Data', or if it is even possible.

Example:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PcdwNHDagfSmtF2Hl27YnrsAsPsF3A5OLuo2YcqGFdk/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C1, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Data!A2:A&Data!B1:E1&"×"&Data!B2:E), "×"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works really well. However, I have a script that will delete any row where the number of actions is 0 or has an error. That means that, if the row with the formula is 0, then the formula gets deleted, Is there a way to re-write the formula so that it can be apply to each cell of the column, so that each cell has its own formula?

Comment: @JohnnyMelou sure. use in C2 and drag down: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2&C$1, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Data!A$2:A&Data!B$1:E$1&"×"&Data!B$2:E), "×"), 2, 0)))`

Comment: Hi again! This worked perfectly, thanks. I thought I was done, but I also need to have Column C sorted from highest to lowest. I came back to the original formula (I will clean up the data in the source sheet), and try using the SORT function in it. The problem is that it doesn't reorganize Column B to match its corresponding values. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @JohnnyMelou that is not possible in one go. you will need to do it in two steps with `=SORT(A2:B, 2, 0)`